# Can not access Jenkins by --prefix value even if --prefix is set

Tags: jenkins

I have set the JENKINS_ARGS using /etc/default/jenkins and start jenkins as a daemon with the www-data user.

The system info page shows that --prefix=/jenkins is set

HOME    /var/www
HUDSON_HOME /var/jenkins
JENKINS_ARGS     --prefix=/jenkins

But still jenkins is only accessible via http://ip:port/ and not http://ip:port/jenkin.

I have also setting the Jenkins URL on the configuration page, but without success.

Do you know more if there is something else I should do?

This is my environment:
Linux robopar12227 2.6.35-22-server #35-Ubuntu SMP Sat Oct 16 22:02:33 UTC 2010 x86_64 GNU/Linux 
java version "1.6.0_20" 
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.9.13) (6b20-1.9.13-0ubuntu1~10.10.1) 
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0-b09, mixed mode) 
Jenkins ver. 1.447

Comment: Can you please post verbatim how JENKINS_ARGS are set in /etc/default/jenkins? (BTW, Jenkins URL in config is for Jenkins to be able to fill out its links correctly - it has no bearing on accessing it).

Comment: JENKINS_ARGS=" --prefix=/jenkins"

Comment: What about DAEMON_ARGS in your /etc/init.d/jenkins?

Comment: DAEMON_ARGS=" server --port=4001 --home=/var/jenkins --daemon"
NAME=jenkins
# Read configuration variable file if it is present
[ -r /etc/default/$NAME ] && . /etc/default/$NAME

start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --make-pidfile --background --chuid www-data --exec $DAEMON -- \
                $DAEMON_ARGS \
                || return 2

Comment: This is the value of DAEMON:

DAEMON="/usr/bin/jenkins "

Answer (score 12):

Add the Prefix to /etc/default/jenkins like so

JENKINS_ARGS="--webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war **--prefix=/jenkins** --httpPort=$HTTP_PORT --ajp13Port=$AJP_PORT"

and restart your jenkins Server

tried on Debian/Ubuntu

Answer (score 9):

I have jenkins running happily in my CentOS system, try the following steps:

1. edit /etc/sysconfig/jenkins, change this line (last line) JENKINS_ARGS="" to JENKINS_ARGS="--prefix=/jenkins" (double hyphen)
2. invoke `sudo service jenkins restart`
3. depending on which port (8080 default - can be changed in the same file) you're running jenkins, you should be able to browse to
   `http://<hostname or ip>:8080/jenkins`

Answer (score 3):

Same problem here upgrading from version 2.319.1 to 2.375.1 on Ubuntu 20.04LTS.
I edited with no results `/etc/default/jenkins`.
Actually the service is located at `/lib/systemd/system/jenkins.service`.
I uncommented `Environment="JENKINS_PREFIX=/jenkins"`
Then did `systemctl daemon-reload` and finally `systemctl restart jenkins`.

It worked again as it was before upgrade

Answer (score 1):

I found this page wrestling with the same problem. Strangely for me setting the PREFIX variable in /etc/default/jenkins didn't work but manually adding in a prefix flag to the JENKINS_ARGS like

```
JENKINS_ARGS="--prefix=$PREFIX --webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war --httpPort=$HTTP_PORT --ajp13Port=$AJP_PORT"
```

did work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please look [at this document](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Running+Jenkins+behind+Apache) - search for words *the context path of Jenkins must be the same between your Apache and Jenkins* . I hope this helps.

Comment: I am not using apache. I would probably use nginx and I know that the context path must be the same. But before hiding jenkins behind nginx I would like to make sure that jenkins is accessible from http://ip:port/jenkins. 

Then I would reverse proxy this from nginx.

Comment: In setups I've seen JENKINS_ARGS is appended to DAEMON_ARGS when Jenkins is being started. Try putting --prefix directly into your DAEMON_ARGS.

Comment: Tried it with 
DAEMON_ARGS=" server --port=4001 --prefix=/jenkins --home=/var/jenkins --daemon"

Didn`t work.

Comment: Just to make sure everything is covered: you did restart the service (sudo service jenkins restart), didn't you?

Comment: Yes. I have tried both restarting and killing it. And then I start jenkins again and it shows "Wait till jenkins is getting ready" or something of that sort

Comment: Ok, I give up. Make sure to ping me when you finally find out what the problem is. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else, like me, reaches this point trying to find a way to set the prefix while starting Jenkins in standalone mode:

Just add `--prefix=/jenkins` to the command line you're using to start the server.
Something like the following:

```
nohup java -jar jenkins.war --prefix=/jenkins > /var/log/jenkins/log 2>&1 &
```

As [malenkiy_scot points out in the first comment on the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9685782/can-not-access-jenkins-by-prefix-value-even-if-prefix-is-set#comment12306945_9685782), the URL in the config is for Jenkins to create links rather than to set the prefix you can access it with.

Comment: A comment from an experienced sysadmin: don't use nohup for running daemons. Use your init system's proper service files in order to have proper logging and management.

Answer (score 0):

Know I am responding way late, but since this stymied me for awhile; I wanted to note that now with systemd, you need to modify the service definition. In that service there is an environment line to uncomment for your prefix.

You can find the location for your os at https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/system-administration/systemd-services/#overriding-service-configurations

Ex.
For my RHEL 9 install:

```
$> vi /usr/lib/systemd/system/jenkins.service
```

change the lines to uncomment Environment="JENKINS_PREFIX=/jenkins" (assuming your prefix is /jenkins)

```
# Servlet context (important if you want to use reverse proxying)
Environment="JENKINS_PREFIX=/jenkins"
```

Remember to reload systemd's files:

```
$> systemctl daemon-reload
```

Reload jenkins:

```
$> systemctl restart jenkins
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue with following steps:

1. Add the Prefix to **/etc/default/jenkins**

   JENKINS_ARGS="--webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war --prefix=/jenkins --httpPort=$HTTP_PORT --ajp13Port=$AJP_PORT"

   but still it is not working because in jenkins service prefix is unset, so
   you need to modify **jenkins service**.
   In **usr/bin/jenkins** file you can see **unset JENKINS_PREFIX** ,that is
   the reason of prefix not working.
2. you need to add two things in main class of jenkins service **usr/bin/jenkins** such as,

`jenkins_prefix="${JENKINS_PREFIX}"` add this line under **unset
JENKINS_WEBROOT** and after that add following condition

```
if [ -z "${JENKINS_PREFIX}" ]; then
            JENKINS_PREFIX=/jenkins
    fi
```

3. restart your jenkins Server.